# The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Basic') do not allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding'

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Error

> The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Basic') do not
>   allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding'
>   ('Anonymous').  Please ensure that the SecurityMode is set to
>   Transport or TransportCredentialOnly.  Additionally, this may be
>   resolved by changing the authentication schemes for this application
>   through the IIS management tool, through the
>   ServiceHost.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemes property, in the
>   application configuration file at the 
>   element, by updating the ClientCredentialType property on the binding,
>   or by adjusting the AuthenticationScheme property on the
>   HttpTransportBindingElement.

Do you know where is problem in web.config? I try log into WCF via basic authentication using windows credentials.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicEndpoint">
          <security mode="Transport" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"
                       proxyCredentialType="None"
                       realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="BasicAuthHttpModule"
        type="Wt.BasicAuthHttpModule, Wt"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using the [Simplified Configuration for WCF Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014.aspx).

If you do not explicitly specify your endpoint service and its bindingConfiguration, WCF would do the following:

- It will associate the default binding to the protocol used (scheme).
- It will load the default bindingConfiguration of the binding type.

For the protocol mapping see this explanation [Simplified Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358768(v=vs.110).aspx)

The default bindingConfiguration does not have a name, so if you give a specific name to your basicHttpBinding configuration you are not overwriting the default binding configuration. It should be instead

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding>
        <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"
                proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```